# mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

I get this error message on pythonanywhere when I reload the app a couple of times. I need to reload the app from pythonanywhere to make it work.

Error message:

`File "/home/sideproject/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 571, in cursor raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.") mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.`
[image]

Anyone Please help me with this.

Server.js file code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from sql_connection import get_sql_connection
import json

import products_dao
import orders_dao
import uom_dao

connection = get_sql_connection()

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/orders', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_orders():
    response = orders_dao.get_all_orders(connection)
    response = jsonify(response)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

sql_connection.py file code

```
import mysql.connector

__cnx = None
def get_sql_connection():
    global __cnx
    if __cnx is None:
        __cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='000000',
                                        host='user.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
                                        database='user$default')
    return __cnx
```

Comment: Could you connect your DB manually, using CLI? Maybe some errors at [log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log.html)?

Comment: everything is working fine locally

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens if your connection is already closed, my suggestion is that you use a try-except-else block and use the Else clause to run the rest of your code if there is no error caught by the Except clause.
it will be something like the following:

```
try:
       cnx = connector.connect(user='user',
                          password='pass',
                          host=creds['host']['MYDB'][0],
                            port=3306,
                          database='MYDB')
except connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == connector.errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DV_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
# the else will happen if there was no error!
else:
    cnx.close()

return cnx
```

Comment: should I completely replace sql_connection.py file code with yours or do I need to make some changes?

Comment: you need to make changes, I didn't modify your code I just showed you an example.